Issue with Page Moving Up and Screen Visibility in MAUI Android
We have encountered an issue in my MAUI Android application that I hope someone can help me resolve. When the on-screen keyboard appears, the entire page moves up, but when the keyboard is dismissed, the page does not return to its original position, leaving a portion of the previous screen visible where the keyboard was.
Steps to Reproduce:

Navigate to a page with an input field.
Tap on the input field to bring up the on-screen keyboard.
Observe that the page shifts upwards
Dismiss the keyboard.
Notice that the page remains shifted, with the bottom of the previous screen still visible.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions on how to fix it? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

I have tested with a new maui .net 8 project and the page will move down to resume the UI when I dismissed the keyboard.
